# How to configure Apache 2.4 to authenticate towards 2 or more remote servers using SSLProxyMachineCertificatePath directive?

Tags: apache, authentication, proxy, reverse-proxy, client-certificates

I configured with success my Apache 2.4 to act as proxy server that can authenticate towards a remote server:

**httpd-ssl.conf**

```
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile "C:/Apache24/conf/myClientCertForWs1.pem"
ProxyPass /ws1/ <HTTPS URL of remote service 1>
ProxyPassReverse /ws1/ <HTTPS URL of remote service 1>
```

Now I need to introduce the authentication towards a second remote server so I changed the above configuration into this way:

**httpd-ssl.conf**

```
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyMachineCertificatePath "C:/Apache24/conf/myClientCertsForWs/"
ProxyPass /ws1/ <HTTPS URL of remote service 1>
ProxyPassReverse /ws1/ <HTTPS URL of remote service 1>
ProxyPass /ws2/ <HTTPS URL of remote service 1>
ProxyPassReverse /ws2/ <HTTPS URL of remote service 1>
```

In "C:/Apache24/conf/myClientCertsForWs/" I placed the 2 client certs renamed with their hash name (54678734.0 and 77b3aaf4.0) generated using these commands:

```
openssl x509 -hash -noout -in myClientCertForWs1.pem

openssl x509 -hash -noout -in myClientCertForWs2.pem
```

Unfortunately this configuration doesn't work: the only certificate used by Apache is the first one so authentication towards the second remote server always fails; it doesn't fail if I remove from the "C:/Apache24/conf/myClientCertsForWs/" the first certificate.

The only working solution I found is configuring 2 VirtualHosts, one for each remote server:

**httpd-ssl.conf**

```
<VirtualHost _default_:9347>
[...]
  SSLProxyEngine on
  SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile "C:/Apache24/conf/myClientCertForWs1.pem"
  ProxyPass /ws1/ <HTTPS URL of remote service 1>
  ProxyPassReverse /ws1/ <HTTPS URL of remote service 1>
[...]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:9348>
[...]
  SSLProxyEngine on
  SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile "C:/Apache24/conf/myClientCertForWs2.pem"
  ProxyPass /ws2/ <HTTPS URL of remote service 2>
  ProxyPassReverse /ws2/ <HTTPS URL of remote service 2>
[...]
</VirtualHost>
```

This solution requires to use 2 ports instead of one and I'd like to avoid it.

Could you kindly help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 2.4.30 and later you can configure SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile in proxy setting i.e

```
 <Proxy HTTPS URL of remote service 1>
SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile "C:/Apache24/conf/myClientCertForWs1.pem"
</Proxy>
<Proxy HTTPS URL of remote service 2>
SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile "C:/Apache24/conf/myClientCertForWs2.pem"
</Proxy>
```